# How to redirect from root folder to public folder in laravel

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4

I have a root folder:

```
/www/
```

but I need to make the user to enter to this folder:

```
/www/public/
```

how can I do it using .htaccess

Comment: You should be pointing root to /www/public/

Comment: @majimboo how can I point it in my share hosting?

Comment: I guess you dont have access to the vhost. added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are on a shared hosting I'll give you this idea, but this shouldn't be the case on a proper development environment.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} public/
RewriteRule ^public/(.*) http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect to public then copy and past to .htaccess file of following code :-

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public [L]
```

This .htaccess file store on root folder of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could move everything in the `/public` folder to the root, then just modify the paths in `index.php`

Comment: No, as it's advisable to keep all the source not in the public directory. But for some hostings, you can't have access to root folders so the only way to do it is this method. But it's not that big of a deal, just look at wordpress having all its core files and folders in the same public directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with one of our servers.
You don't actually have to use the public folder, it's just an extra security precaution.

Open the bootstrap folder. In there you will find a file called "paths.php". Open it and it will contain an array. Change the public value to `__DIR__.'/..'`.

Then you can just use the folder with all of your laravel directories as your public folder.

You would of course have to move the default files (.htaccess, index.php and robots.txt) from the public folder, to your laravel folder.